# Copying all files from folder incl. subfolder into a new folder Win 10

Tags: windows, file, explorer, copying

I have copied all files from a directory including all subdirectories in Windows by going to the parent folder and search for * and then marking all files excluding the directories. If I copy them to a new directory the number of files in th new directory is lower compared to the source directory (~50000 files) by ~1200. How could that be? Are not all files found through the search?

Thanks, cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you're counting files by looking at the Folder Properties, it gives you a count of all files in that directory and its subdirectories. You may have 1200 files in the directories you excluded from your copy operation.